# How to update a row in a MySQL database using Ruby's Sequel toolkit?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

This should be the simplest thing but for some reason it's eluding me completely.

I have a Sequel connection to a database named `DB`. It's using the Mysql2 engine if that's important.

I'm trying to update a single record in a table in the database. The short loop I'm using looks like this:

```
dataset = DB["SELECT post_id, message FROM xf_post WHERE message LIKE '%#{match}%'"]
dataset.each do |row|
  new_message = process_message(row[:message])
  # HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO UPDATE THE ROW IN THE DATABASE!
end
```

I've tried:

```
dataset.where('post_id = ?', row[:post_id]).update(message: new_message)
```

Which is what [the Sequel cheat sheet recommends](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Update-2FDelete+rows).

And:

```
DB["UPDATE xf_post SET message = ? WHERE post_id = ?", new_message, row[:post_id]]
```

Which should be raw SQL executed by the Sequel connector. Neither throws an error or outputs any error message (I'm using a logger with the Sequel connection). But both calls fail to update the records in the database. The data is unchanged when I query the database after running the code.

How can I make the update call function properly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are using a raw SQL dataset, so the `where` call isn't going to change the SQL, and `update` is just going to execute the raw SQL.  Here's what you want to do:

```
dataset = DB[:xf_post].select(:post_id, :message).
            where(Sequel.like(:message, "%#{match}%"))
```

That will make the `where`/`update` combination work.

Note that your original code has a trivial SQL injection vulnerability if `match` depends on user input, which this new code avoids. You may want to consider using `Dataset#escape_like` if you want to escape metacharacters inside `match`, otherwise if `match` depends on user input, it's possible for users to use very complex matching syntax that the database may execute slowly or not handle properly.

Note that the reason that

```
DB["UPDATE xf_post SET message = ? WHERE post_id = ?", new_message, row[:post_id]]
```

doesn't work is because it only creates a dataset, it doesn't execute it.  You can actually call `update` on that dataset to run the query and return number of affected rows.